# startAnimation() is not being called

Tags: android-animation

I am trying to implement the Youtube style sliding menu with two fragments. I have created a custom animation that will change the width of the left fragment with the toggle function is called on pressing the app icon on the Action bar. The Expand.java will increase the width while Collapse.java will decrease the width. When i call the startAnimation() function from the onCreate() of the MainActivity.java, it works fine. But when i call it from withing the toggle(), it doesnt work, though the constructor of Expand.java and Collapse.java are

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout 
 android:id="@+id/f1"     
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="0dip"  
    >

 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/listFragment"     
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
    class="com.surv.ui123.FragLeft" >

 </fragment>
 </LinearLayout>
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/f2"     
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/detailFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"     
    android:layout_height="match_parent"        
    class="com.surv.ui123.FragRight" >
      </fragment>

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

FragLeft.java

```
package com.surv.ui123;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragLeft extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragleft,
    container, false);


return view;
} 
}
```

FragRight.java

```
package com.surv.ui123;


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragRight extends Fragment {

 @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragright,
        container, false);      
return view;
}
}
```

Expand.java

```
package com.surv.ui123;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class Expand extends Animation implements Animation.AnimationListener {
private View view;
private static long ANIMATION_DURATION;
private int FromWidth;
private int ToWidth;

public Expand(View v, int FromWidth, int ToWidth) {

    this.view = v;
    ANIMATION_DURATION = 1;
    this.FromWidth = FromWidth;
    this.ToWidth = ToWidth;
    setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    setRepeatCount(10);
    setFillAfter(false);
    setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Expand",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    setAnimationListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutParams lyp =  view.getLayoutParams();     
    lyp.width = lyp.width+(int)(ToWidth/10);
    view.setLayoutParams(lyp);

}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Strarted     Expand",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

Collapse.java

```
package com.surv.ui123;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.view.animation.AccelerateInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Collapse extends Animation implements Animation.AnimationListener {

private View view;
private static long ANIMATION_DURATION;

private int FromWidth;
private int ToWidth;
public Collapse(View v, int ToWidth, int FromWidth) {

    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),"Collapse",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.view = v;      
    ANIMATION_DURATION = 1;
    this.FromWidth = FromWidth;
    this.ToWidth = ToWidth;
    setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION);
    setRepeatCount(10);
    setFillAfter(false);
    setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    setAnimationListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    LayoutParams lyp =  view.getLayoutParams();     
    lyp.width = lyp.width-(int)(ToWidth/10);
    view.setLayoutParams(lyp);  
}

@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



}

}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.surv.ui123;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;



 public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

 LinearLayout MenuList,RFrg;
 boolean isExpanded=true;    
 int screenWidth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MenuList = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.f1);
    RFrg=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.f2);
    LayoutParams lyp =  RFrg.getLayoutParams();     

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        lyp.width = screenWidth;

        RFrg.setLayoutParams(lyp);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);               

}

@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem item)           {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // app icon in action bar clicked; go home
                toggle();

                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    public void toggle()
    {       

    isExpanded=!isExpanded;

        if (isExpanded) {
            Collapse x= new Collapse(MenuList, 0,(int)(screenWidth*0.75));
            MenuList.startAnimation(x);
        }else {
            Expand d=new Expand(MenuList, 0,(int)(screenWidth*0.75));

            MenuList.startAnimation(d);
        }
    }                                                   


 }
```

Comment: the toggle() is working after adding some views in the fragment. :)...

Comment: Do you really expect someone to go thru so much code to help solve you issue. Please read the FAQ, and put out a smaller piece of code. Way smaller in your case.